# Display issue in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I have one query regarding display in internet explorer. While edit one particular field then save, after that changes are reflecting in chrome but same changes are not reflecting in internet explorer.Could someone suggest reason behind this and guide further?

Comment: The question you asked is broad and not answerable.  Please include the HTML/CSS/JavaScript code related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After analysis and debugging I came to know that issue was related with cache clearance of internet explorer. Once cache and cookies are cleared then applied changes are reflecting in IE as well. So it is resolved now .Thanks:)